# How to change the namespace of a resource file in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

At this moment the default namespace for resources (resx files) is `ProjectName.Resources`.

I would like to change this default to being just `Resources`.

[image]

What I have tried to do here is manually change the namespace in `Address.Designer.cs`. While that seems to work at first, the default is reset after changing one of the values in the resx file.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried to set the project's default namespace in Project properties?

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you want to change it? It is the defacto industry standard to have `Vendor.ApplicationName.FolderPosition` as namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you cannot change the namespace as easily as it was in old ASP.NET projects just by changing the `Custom Tool Namespace` in the properties section of a resx file. Simplest thing you can do is create a `Class Library` project named `Resources` in your solution and add `Address.resx` to it. Then change its `Access Modifier` to `Public`.

[image]

Comment: I do not have those options. All I can see is `File Name` and `Full Path`